# Mongdb combined limit and sort when using find function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have db mongdb example with document a and document b

```
a_id type 
1     1
2     2
3     3 
4     4
```

Now. I want to extract the last N (1,2,3,4,5,....) values in table b in the same order as in the example above. But if I use skip function :

```
b.find().skip(M)
```

if M > N then result empty =>  wrong. I want dynamic M. 
If I use sort and limit then it does not give the correct order.

```
 b.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(M)
```

result:

```
4 4
3 3
```

I want a solution!

Comment: `$natural` does not do what you are presuming it does, and usually should not be used. You likely just want `,sort({ _id: -1 })`, but your question is a little unclear. Probably because you are likely abstracting instead of presenting your real case. But if you want "order of insertion", then since `ObjectId` ( which is usually the default for `_id` ) is "monotonic" or "ever increasing in value", then this is usually the truest indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same skip() to access the last N documents in the collection.

N = Last N documents to be accessed

So the query is

b.find().skip(b.count() - N).pretty()

or you can play with the mongo shell just as javascript like

var totalCount = b.count()

db.find().skip(totalCount - N).pretty()